# Font awesome - change the inner "i" color in class="fa-info-circle"

Tags: css, font-awesome

Is it possible to change the inner "i" color within `<i class="fa fa-info-circle">` ?

E.g. - in [this fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/Lgq1k4uc/1/) make just the "i" with red color .

Comment: You can try by wrapping it in a div and background color as red. Make the div circular with same width & height as your info circle icon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should implement this like this:

html

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background2"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-info fa-stack-1x"></i> 
 </span>
```

css

```
.icon-background2 {
    color: #564363;
}

.fa-info {
  color:pink;
}
```

JSFiddle Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/codejhonny/8feo4k4x/

Comment: yep, This is the easiest and safest way to accomplish this.

Comment: Wouldn't say that this is either easy nor safe, you stack two elements on each other. @Peter Wilson answer only requires to modify the css. But still if it's okey for OP, so be it.

Comment: Both answers are good. I meant that it is safer because it doesn't require border-radius (unsupported IE8, OperaMini) or anything except another element in the html. Both answers are valid and will work in most scenarios

Comment: @Frutis Both solutions involve stacking two items on top of each other, this one uses another fa icon in the html and the other creates an element with rounded corners in css. I'd say Jhonny's solution is safer, because if the size/shape of the i icon changed (e.g. a font awesome update, or text scaling) you'd expect the fa-circle icon to change consistently.

Answer (score 2):

this icon is transparent so you could reach this but give it background color

```
.icon-background1 {
color: blue;
}
.fa-info-circle:before {
  content: "\f05a";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq1k4uc/7/

Comment: 50px wouldn't leave any red spots arround the circle. Good solution

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the inner `i` color. But you can try this:

```
.icon-background1 {
    color: blue;
    vertical-align:middle
}
a.info {
    position: relative;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.info:before {
    background: red;  
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 4px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

Here is fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/Lgq1k4uc/4/

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before too. Assuming the info circle icon is also transparent in the middle like mine was, you can just add a div with a white background and position it absolutely behind the icon, using a lower z-index value (but equal to or higher than the container/parent element).

Example:

```
<!-- the fa icon div -->
<div class="fa-exclamation-triangle" ...></div>

<!-- the div with white background -->
<div class="exclamation-inside"></div>

<!-- CSS -->
.fa-exclamation-triangle {
    z-index: 2000;
    /* some positioning etc */
}

.exclamation-inside {
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 18px;
    top: 12px;
    left: 18px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is simpler https://jsfiddle.net/maksuco/3adjtLop/7/

```html
 <span style="font-size: 10rem">
  <i class="fa fa-check check big"></i> big
 </span>
 <br>
 <br>
 <i class="fa fa-check check "></i> normal
```

```css
.check {
  display: inline;
  color: #8D58B1;
  font-size: 80%;
  &:before {
    padding: .5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #EFE6F3;
  }
  &.big {
    &:before {
      padding: .2em;
    }
  }
}
```